# Compile the installer then giving warning Dll is under Windows System File Protection

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I am facing the below warning while compiling the installer project during the creation of the setup file.

> WARNING: 'System.IO.Compression.dll' should be excluded because its
> source file
> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.dll'
> is under Windows System File Protection.
>
> WARNING: 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll' should be excluded because
> its source file
> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'
> is under Windows System File Protection.
>
> WARNING: 'System.Net.Http.dll' should be excluded because its source
> file
> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'
> is under Windows System File Protection.
>
> WARNING: 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll' should be excluded
> because its source file
> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll'
> is under Windows System File Protection.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and the WPF application with c#.

Can I delete this kind of dlls reference from the installer project or will keep it as it is?

Comment: You shouldn't be referencing dll out your gac in an app.

Comment: @Andy, Thank you. I will try removing references.

Comment: @Andy: I removed references. Tested with different machines. It is working fine. Thank you.